# PHP PDO fetch returns FALSE when no records found AND on failure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, exception, fetch

The PDO method [**fetch()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-returnvalues) returns the value `FALSE` both when no records are found **AND** on failure (e.g. when something goes wrong regarding the database access).

I need to be able to differentiate between the two situations and to handle each one in the corresponding manner:

- to display a message to the user when no records are found and
- to throw an exception on failure.

So, my question: is there a way to handle the result in a proper manner?

Thank you for your time.

P.S.: I would have expected to receive an empty array as result, when no records are found, and the value `FALSE` when something goes wrong. Like in the case of [**fetchAll()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-returnvalues) method.

---

### UPDATE:

**The method `PdoStatement::fetch` throws exceptions on failure, instead of `FALSE`. Such a case is demonstrated in my answer:**

- [**Simulate a PDO fetch failure situation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343196/simulate-a-pdo-fetch-failure-situation)

In conclusion, as @pucky124 already said, the differentiation is easy so achieve:

- **`PDOStatement::fetch` returns `FALSE` if no records are found.**
- **`PDOStatement::fetch` throws exceptions on failure.**

Comment: Why not use `PDOStatement::rowCount`?

Comment: @ErikKralj Thank you for your comment. An interesting idea. I'll test it right now. You can make it as an answer as well.

Comment: "No records found" means *an empty (or exhausted) result set*. A query matching nothing is not a failed query, it's just an empty result set. Trying to fetch from a result set which is empty (or exhausted) returns `false`, it's also not a failure. Real failures due to invalid queries or failed database connections occur at the `query` or `prepare` stages; if those succeeded then there's almost nothing that could fail while fetching.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for your comment. Give me some minutes to answer, please.

Comment: @deceze Sorry for beeing late with my answer. I read your comment with great interest and attention. Well, I don't consider emty result a failure. Nor the second case. Of the real failures on query and prepare stage I'm very aware. You mentioned "almost nothing that could fail". Exactly this "almost" is the key. I'm in the position of trying to find out if there is such a situation at all. If not, then I know for sure that the returned `FALSE` of a `fetch()` is only in regard of an empty result, and I can handle it with ease.

Comment: @deceze But, if at least one real failure case will arise on using `fetch()` moment, and it will return `FALSE`, so NO exception will be thrown by PDO, then there would be a problem... :-)

Comment: @ErikKralj I finally found a case, which allowed me to simulate a failure situation of `PDOStatement::fetch()`. An exception was thrown. I also posted a detailed answer: [Simulate a PDO fetch failure situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343196/simulate-a-pdo-fetch-failure-situation). So, one can conclude, that `fetch()` does indeed throw exceptions on failure, and that the `FALSE` value is only returned when no records are found. Thanks again for your comments!

Comment: @deceze I finally found a case, which allowed me to simulate a failure situation of `PDOStatement::fetch()`. An exception was thrown. I also posted a detailed answer: [Simulate a PDO fetch failure situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343196/simulate-a-pdo-fetch-failure-situation). So, one can conclude, that `fetch()` does indeed throw exceptions on failure, and that the `FALSE` value is only returned when no records are found. Thanks again for your comments!

Comment: @aendeerei Nice. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is for. Use it like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8'
            , 'user'
            , 'pass'
            , [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ]
    );
```

When used this way errors actually get thrown as exceptions. This means that should an error occur with fetch (or other methods using this pdo object) an exception will be thrown and the method won't actually return at all. This is a very effective way of handling errors in PDO. Now you know that if fetch returns a value no errors occured and therefore if it is false then the query returned no records.

Comment: Indeed, this would be the right way, under the condition that everybody know, that `PDOStatement::fetch` throw an exception on failure. That's why I think, that it would be good, if you'd put a reference to my other question [Simulate a PDO fetch failure situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343196/simulate-a-pdo-fetch-failure-situation) in this answer of yours, too. Thank you again for all your efforts! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Connect extends PDO
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vicode", 'root', '',
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        $this->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }
}
?>
```