# PDOStatement::fetch occasionally returns false, but errorInfo() is empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having strange problem with PDO. Code is like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
  $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ... FROM .... ");
  $sth->execute();
  $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if (!$result) {
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    print_r($sth->errorInfo());
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

So it's very common use of PDO. And the code works as expected most of the time. But occasionally `$result` is false. What is strange is that both PDO::errorInfo() and PDOStatement::errorInfo() return empty array like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(5) "00000"
  [1]=> NULL
  [2]=> NULL
}
```

I suspect there is some problem with MySQL connection, however connection works fine, doesn't throw any exceptions, MySQL server is idle, there is enough connections available. There are no errors in MySQL or PHP log.

So my question is, how to troubleshoot this problem more ? I need to know, why sometimes fetch() fails with false and there is no information about error in errorInfo()

Comment: Not sure if this will make any difference, but perhaps something like `try { $sth->execute(); } catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); }` to begin with?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, there is always a row to retrieve, the table is still the same, and in about 10 requests, 1 fails with returning false.

Comment: @icecub As I have stated in my question - it doesn't throw any Exceptions at all, just fetch() returns false.

Comment: Can you include the proper `prepare()` statement, I would have expected there to be some sort of binding values bit if your preparing your statements.

Comment: Right, sorry I forgot to include that you need to set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` in your PDO object for that to work. It will allow errors to be thrown as exceptions. As you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342798/php-pdo-fetch-returns-false-when-no-records-found-and-on-failure/46352628

Comment: @icecub I have updated my live code and code in question with your suggestion, however there is no difference. Still no error is shown and no exception is thrown :-(

Comment: With those options set, something will be shown unless no record is returned. What you could do, just to be absolutely sure, is add `if ($sth->rowCount() === 0) { echo "No records found"; }`.

Comment: @icecub yes, you're right, when `fetch()` returns false, then `rowCount` returns 0, else it returns 1. But as I said before, the table is still the same. No updates are beeing made and condition is still the same. So it must be some problem with MySQL itself. But how to troubleshoot it more ?

Comment: I'm afraid that's the limit of my knowledge on how to troubleshoot the issue. Perhaps you should explain how you're encountering the issue? Like, are you refreshing the page an x amount of times and eventually it returns false? Is it the exact same query that returns true most of the time but randomly returns false? Perhaps add a small screenshot of the row in your databse and your actual query to the question? Give us the actual code instead of a mock up so we can test for ourselves. I mean, helping you troubleshoot is hard without having all the information available to us.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found out what was causing this strange behaviour. I have 2 very similar databases on this MySQL server. And I use persistent connections with both of them. And somehow (???)  PHP's PDO is sometimes created with different database selected.

I would never expect this, because in `new PDO();` I have right database I need to use. But for some strange reason connection is made to different database. It has to do something with using persistent connections, because when I disable using persistent connection, everything works fine.

So I am probably going to ask another question - this time - why PDO connects to different database when it's supposed to when using persistence.