# Why PHP PDO connects to different database when using persistent connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I connect to MySQL using PHP's PDO like this:

```
$driver_options[PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT] = true;
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $user, $pass, $driver_options);
```

I have 2 databases (let's call them database_A and database_B) on this server and sometimes very strange thing happens. Even though, $db_name is 100% set to 'database_A', connection is made to 'database_B'.

It's happening completely random. I can run the same script 10 times over again and everything is fine. And 11th time this problem happens.

I would never expect this to happen. It gave me [a lot of headache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422388/pdostatementfetch-occasionally-returns-false-but-errorinfo-is-empty). Can anyone explain it ? And is the only solution not to use persistence ?

Comment: Can it be that you had configured database_B earlier for some test or similar? Then this might be a caching issue...

Comment: Do not ask me why and how but I once heard of putting a space between `mysql:` and `hostname` like `mysql: host` to do the trick on connections problems.

Comment: Yeap --> http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php Example #4 Notes

Comment: @PeterM Unfortunately this trick didn't work for me.

Comment: @Evhz But there is no word about problems with having multiple databases on server.

Comment: @Frodik it is commented the problems with cache in the ODBC driver level. Probably you'd need to review the setup, or try other versions of the driver with the same script (*if you have rights do that in the system you use*)

Comment: @Evhz I am using PDO with MySQL, that's not ODBC, is it?

Comment: does your database user have access to both of databases?

Comment: Different values for `$db_name`, but same value for `$host`?

Comment: @Miron just because PHP7.x no longer supports PDO anymore it doesn't mean that the codebase should be migrated over to support PHP7.x

Comment: Set and try different credential for different databases.

Comment: @Miron if PHP 7.x doesn't support PDO, someone should tell this to the PHP 7 guys. They apparently don't know yet, and the PDO module is available (on Ubuntu inside the `php-mysql` module). There is not even a deprecation notice (as there is for e.g. `mysql_*` functions, which are a different country from PDO).

Comment: Did you try this -- remove or set null to pdo object "$db" before creating another one database connection.

Comment: I am pretty sure that all is ok with your MySQL connection and PDO. You just do not provide us all code you have. So can you please create one page with the code that brings the error time to time when I can call that page (php script) 100 times and to reproduce the issue? But I want you to guarantee that you provide full code of that page. I am absolutely sure that your issue has nothing to   with PDO. You just have different calls somewhere in your application where you reconnect to database or pass the connection somehow and switch the database.  Can you provide github project?

Comment: Another question: you asked about `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` to remove as an option. Did you try? does it solve your problem? so when you remove that param everything works ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT is partially supported and is dependent on the the PHP version and SQL server you're using.
I would recommend never setting this attribute to true in the drive options due to it's instability.

I was able to replicate your case and i found that the ODBC Connection Pooling layer was caching the connection and since your connection is being set to persistent, the cache was being reset each time i made a new connection.

Comment: OP asked.I assume he is probably using technology that can not yet be migrated to the latest versions.

Comment: Could you provide steps to reproduce this bug please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$driver_options[PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT] = true;
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $user, $pass,    $driver_options);
```

When you do the above, the PDO connection is placed in the "persistent connection pool", but the pool purpose **is not to cache the database**, but rather the memory allocation, authentication and setup groundwork. *That* is what uses time (not so much, at that).

Whatever else you supply in the `new PDO()` call is **LOST**.

And if you have two databases with the same credentials, you can get them swapped at random -- as you experienced.

So, **do not** specify the DB in the `new PDO` statement, but use the `USE databasename` SQL statement as soon as the new PDO object is ready.

Or, as PankajKumar suggests, set up different credentials for the two DBs. Then the mistaken cache hit will not happen (but is wont to happen again as soon as someone reuses those same credentials - such as 'ubuntu/ubuntu' or 'root/').

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are running this in production, or a dev system which is reloaded not so often.

Therefore please restart all your php workers/instances/threads and check if the problem occurs again.

I believe one of these processes is holding your old configuration. And silently causes your errors, randomly when your webserver actually chooses to use the old thing.